# how can separate classes is begin with an underline?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I fetch the classes of a `<div>` and save it in a variable.

this classes are following:

```
item drag drop img-circle _RS _CS ui-draggable ui-droppable ui-draggable-dragging
```

how can separate the classes that begins with an underline, like:  `_CS` ?

Comment: Wow, I would have said classes starting with an `_` were invalid. And [I'd've been wrong](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier).

Comment: I think I would have done just `indexOf('_') === 0 `?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`String.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to get them having an array as result:

```
var classes = "_A drag drop img-circle _RS _CS ui-draggable a-_NASTY ui-xyz _z";
var underscoreClasses = classes.match(/(^| )_\S+/g);
console.log(underscoreClasses); // ["_A", " _RS", " _CS", " _z"]
```

If you need the string (not the array), you can use [`Array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to make it happen:

```
var classes = "_A drag drop img-circle _RS _CS ui-draggable a-_NASTY ui-xyz _z";
var underscoreClasses2 = classes.match(/(^| )_\S+/g).join("");
console.log(underscoreClasses2); // "_A _RS _CS _z"
```

[**Demo JsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/dnAEF/).

Answer (score 1):

Use `.split` and `.filter`.

```
var classes = "item drag drop img-circle _RS _CS ui-draggable ui-droppable ui-draggable-dragging";
classes.split(/\s+/).filter(function(c) { return c[0] === "_"; })
=> ["_RS", "_CS"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
class = "item drag drop img-circle _RS _CS ui-draggable ui-droppable ui-draggable-dragging"
classes = class.split(" ")
underscoreclasses = []
$.each(classes, function(id, value) {
    if (value.slice(0, 1) == "_") {
        underscoreclasses.push(value)
    }
})

console.log(underscroreclasses)
```

It is using the [split method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) and the [slice method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp).